# GluonFX:build failing seemingly due to issues with bytebuddy and Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx, fxml, gluon

I'm building a mobile app with `GluonFX` and `Spring` with `Maven`. Upon trying to build the app, I'm running into the issues below, leading to the build failing.

I'm using the `x64` native tools command line from `VS 2019` to build it, like `Gluon` instructs in its documentation. I'm running this command to start it: `"mvn gluonfx:build -e -X -f pom.xml"`. It seems like I'm running into an issue with `graalVM` conflicting with `Spring`/`bytebuddy` involving reflection that causes classes to be initialized that should not be initialized until runtime. However, I've tried `--initialize-at-run-time` arguments for just about every class I could think of being potentially problematic, but all the same classes still seem to get initialized. Any ideas of what is causing this/how to fix it? The code snippet below contains most of my error message starting from where things appear to start going wrong using the `--trace-class-initialization` argument. I can provide any more information needed.

```
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] Error: Classes that should be initialized at run time got initialized during image building:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]  net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:174)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$InDefinedShape$AbstractBase$ForLoadedExecutable was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$InDefinedShape$AbstractBase$ForLoadedExecutable.<clinit>(MethodDescription.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.get(MethodList.java:183)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.get(MethodList.java:133)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:371)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.FilterableList$AbstractBase.filter(FilterableList.java:124)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation$1 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation$1.<clinit>(Super.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:126)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic.<clinit>(Argument.java:97)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3837)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3859)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:267)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumValue(AnnotationParser.java:479)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:344)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:717)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerTypesForMethod(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:506)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.processMethodMetadata(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:284)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.duringAnalysis(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:185)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionFeature.duringAnalysis(ReflectionFeature.java:189)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$10(NativeImageGenerator.java:726)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator$$Lambda$1717/0x00000007c3246dc8.accept(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:74)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$11(NativeImageGenerator.java:726)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator$$Lambda$550/0x00000007c389dad8.apply(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.runAnalysis(PointsToAnalysis.java:751)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:723)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:558)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:515)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:615)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic$2 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic$2.<clinit>(Argument.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic.<clinit>(Argument.java:117)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$2 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$2.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:79)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$8 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$8.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:141)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$DynamicClassLoader was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$DynamicClassLoader.<clinit>(JavaDispatcher.java:1198)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:459)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:452)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:776)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.doPrivileged(JavaDispatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.<clinit>(JavaDispatcher.java:87)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java:8659)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:174)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$4 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$4.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:99)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$9 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$9.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:152)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:126)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3837)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3859)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:267)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseEnumValue(AnnotationParser.java:479)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:344)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue(Method.java:717)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.registerTypesForMethod(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:506)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.processMethodMetadata(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:284)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionDataBuilder.duringAnalysis(ReflectionDataBuilder.java:185)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.reflect.hosted.ReflectionFeature.duringAnalysis(ReflectionFeature.java:189)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$10(NativeImageGenerator.java:726)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator$$Lambda$1717/0x00000007c3246dc8.accept(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.FeatureHandler.forEachFeature(FeatureHandler.java:74)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$runPointsToAnalysis$11(NativeImageGenerator.java:726)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator$$Lambda$550/0x00000007c389dad8.apply(Unknown Source)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.PointsToAnalysis.runAnalysis(PointsToAnalysis.java:751)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.runPointsToAnalysis(NativeImageGenerator.java:723)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:558)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:515)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:407)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:585)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:615)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$3 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$3.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:89)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:69)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.<clinit>(JavaDispatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java:8659)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:174)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation$2 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation$2.<clinit>(Super.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:143)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic$1 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic$1.<clinit>(Argument.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Argument$BindingMechanic.<clinit>(Argument.java:97)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$AbstractBase.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:174)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$1 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$1.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:69)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$5 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$5.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:110)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.utility.GraalImageCode was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.GraalImageCode.<clinit>(GraalImageCode.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$DynamicClassLoader.invoker(JavaDispatcher.java:1320)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:459)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher$InvokerCreationAction.run(JavaDispatcher.java:452)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.executePrivileged(AccessController.java:776)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.doPrivileged(JavaDispatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.utility.dispatcher.JavaDispatcher.<clinit>(JavaDispatcher.java:87)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.<clinit>(TypeDescription.java:8659)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:174)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$7 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$7.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:131)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$ForLoadedMethod was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodDescription$ForLoadedMethod.<clinit>(MethodDescription.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.get(MethodList.java:183)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.get(MethodList.java:133)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:371)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.FilterableList$AbstractBase.filter(FilterableList.java:124)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB] net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$6 was unintentionally initialized at build time. net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation caused initialization of this class with the following trace:
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode$6.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.StringMatcher$Mode.<clinit>(StringMatcher.java:120)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.named(ElementMatchers.java:651)
[Tue Aug 15 13:20:28 CDT 2023][INFO] [SUB]      at net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Super$Instantiation.<clinit>(Super.java:175)
```